# How do I serve json using spark's routing?

Tags: java, json, http, request, spark-java

I am using [spark](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html) to develop a small web application. I am coming off of using python's tornado framework, so a lot of this is new for me. I need to be able to serve json from the backend to the frontend. So, using their example, something like this.

```
import static spark.Spark.*;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        get("/hello", (req, res) -> {
            return {
                "foo" : "bar"
            };
        });
    }
}
```

So to summarize, I want the ability to send a dictionary, a list, whatever is considered valid json to the frontend.

However, I understand that dicts/lists are not basic types in Java. Does anyone know how I could do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the section Response Transformers at the [documentation](http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html).

Comment: How do  I get access to the ResponseTransformer class? When I try and compile my code, I get the error 

"error: cannot find symbol
    public class JsonTransformer implements ResponseTransformer {"

Comment: How do I import this? I am importing the rest of spark using "import static spark.Spark.*;" as in the example

Comment: nevermind..... "implements spark.ResponseTransformer" seemed to do the trick. I'll give you the accept if this ends up working.